# trying to understand angular ui-router states & templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking at some Angular code and trying to build on top of it, but I'm having a very difficult time trying to make a multi part search form.

The flow I'm trying to go for is:

1. Enter the `category`
2. Enter the `location` and `search_radius`
3. Enter the `min_price` to `max_price`.  In the future, there will be more features here.

And on step 3, there will be a submit button.

Now, that's just what I *plan* on doing.  I'm struggling to actually work with the 3 states.

Here is the existing code I am working with.  I'm trying to break up the current form into 3 sections as mentioned above.

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('search_local', [])
  .config(SearchLocal);

function SearchLocal($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('main.searchLocal', {
    url: '/search/:id',
    views: {
      "search-local" : {
        template: '<search-local></search-local>',
      }
    },
    title : 'Search for local listings'
  });
}

SearchLocal.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];
```

To break the current form that's in search-local.html into 3 views, I want to create 3 states. I tried adding a second `.state( ... )` to the SearchLocal() but nothing seems to be working.

Here's all I'm trying to do -

I made a step-one.html, a step-two.html, and step-three.html.

Each file just has a `<a ui-sref="main.stepX">Next</a>` to go to the next state, but Next does not show up.

Comment: Is Next not showing up or is the Next link not populating a valid `href` attribute? If the latter is true, it's possible your route is not resolving correctly. In otherwords, whatever you are putting in `ui-sref` is not matching the actual route definition you've setup via the provider.

Comment: thanks.  for the steps then, how do I define the view?  Everything is going into the search-local.html file, right?  So for step-one, I'm probably defining it wrong.

Comment: Does such a minimal form really need all those routes? Or does each one populate data as well?

Comment: I would just simplify your route definition. You are currently using the named views feature of `ui-router`, you don't need that yet and they are complex and finicky anyway. Just make a simple defintion that has a `url`, a `templateUrl`, and a `controller`. If you need the other 2 states, make 2 more simple routes like that. Otherwise, just do everything in one route (in the controller or via a service injected into the controller) as suggested by @charlietfl

Comment: So the form is actually complex, but right now one has to scroll a bit to fill it out.  I'm trying to move the form over to using ionic slide box so it can be broken into 3 steps.

Comment: Also note that using dots in state names implies nested child states and you don't seem to have a `main` parent

Comment: If you want more help with this you might need to post more code for better contextual clarity.